# resize std::string without initializing memory

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring

I'm using a C routine to write to an std::string's datafield. This is a contrived example, in reality I'm getting a non-null terminated string and its size via network:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

const char* str = "Some examplory string.."; 

int main()
{
    std::string some_str;
    some_str.resize(strlen(str));
    std::strcpy(&some_str.front(), str);
    printf(some_str.c_str());
}
```

Now according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) there's no overload for `resize()` which just resizes and does not initialize memory with '\0' or something else. But why should I pay for that if all I'm doing is overwriting it again? Can this somehow be avoided?

Comment: It is arriving soon: [`std::basic_string::resize_and_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite)

Comment: @273K Thanks! Which probably means it can't be done right now haha

Comment: It is supported by GCC12, Clang14 and MSVC19.31. See [C++23 library features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B23_library_features).

Comment: If you are frequently appending to the string, it looks like a case for std::ostringstream perhaps?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Sorry I'm not touching iostream on my tender embedded system :X Also I doubt that it will have less overhead.

Comment: @glades Ok I understood that you wanted to accumulate the string. Why don' t you just use std::vector<char> instead then?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher But how would I extract the string afterwards?

Comment: `std::string(chunk.data(),chunk.size())`?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher indeed that could work

Comment: Don't resize() and strcpy(). What about appending a range: str.append( some_str.begin(), some_str.end() ); ?

Comment: @André: You'd probably want to wrap the C string in a `std::string_view`. Your suggestion implies a string copy in order to obtain `some_str`, which you need for `some_str.end()`.

Comment: @MSalters. Oops, I missed that one. But still, he could use basic_string::append( const CharT* s, size_type count ).

Comment: Why not just use the assignment operator (`some_str = str;`), which should surely be at least as efficient?

Answer (score 2):

For c++23, we have [resize_and_overwrite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite)

For old standard, [let's hack it!](https://godbolt.org/z/KnfGfTjzP)

It works well on gcc5+, clang12+, msvc 1921+

```cpp
// Our hacker function, resize a std::string without initializing memory
// (but still has '\0' in the end of string)
inline void resize(std::string& str, std::size_t sz);

#if __cpp_lib_string_resize_and_overwrite >= 202110L
    inline void resize(std::string& str, std::size_t sz) {
        str.resize_and_overwrite(sz, [](char*, std::size_t sz) {
            return sz;
            });
    }
#elif (defined(__clang_major__) && __clang_major__ <= 11) ||(defined(_MSC_VER)&& _MSC_VER<=1920)
    // old clang has bug in global friend function. discard it.
    // old msvc don't support visit private, discard it.
    inline void resize(std::string& str, std::size_t sz) { str.resize(sz); }
#else

#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION)
    template <typename Money_t, Money_t std::string::* p>
    class string_thief {
    public:
        friend void string_set_length_hacker(std::string& bank, std::size_t sz) {
            (bank.*p)(sz);
        }
    };
#elif defined(_MSVC_STL_VERSION)
    template <typename Money_t, Money_t std::string::* p>
    class string_thief {
    public:
        friend void string_set_length_hacker(std::string& bank, std::size_t sz) {
            (bank.*p)._Myval2._Mysize = sz;
        }
    };
#endif

#if defined(__GLIBCXX__)  // libstdc++
    template class string_thief<void(std::string::size_type),
        &std::string::_M_set_length>;
#elif defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION)
    template class string_thief<void(std::string::size_type),
        &std::string::__set_size>;
#elif defined(_MSVC_STL_VERSION)
    template class string_thief<decltype(std::string::_Mypair),
        &std::string::_Mypair>;
#endif

#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || \
    defined(_MSVC_STL_VERSION)
    void string_set_length_hacker(std::string& bank, std::size_t sz);
#endif

    inline void resize(std::string& str, std::size_t sz) {
#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || \
    defined(_MSVC_STL_VERSION)
        str.reserve(sz);
        string_set_length_hacker(str, sz);
        str[sz] = '\0';
#else
        str.resize(sz);
#endif
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++23 you can use [`std::string::resize_and_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite). Example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::size_t capacity = 10; // Doesn't include the final `\0`, room for it is added automatically.
    str.resize_and_overwrite(capacity, [](char *ptr, std::size_t count)
    {
        std::strcpy(ptr, "1234567890");
        // Writing the terminating `\0` is optional, the character at `ptr[return_value]` is overwritten with `\0` anyway.
        return count; // Doesn't include the final `\0`.
    });

    std::cout << str << '\n'; // 1234567890
}
```

It first allocates `capacity` bytes of storage, calls the lambda to fill it (the second parameter of the lambda redundantly receives the same `capacity` value).

The lambda then returns the final string size, which normally must match `capacity`, but can be less, if the lambda decides to write less bytes.

Cppreference claims that you must initialize the whole string in the lambda, otherwise the behavior is undefined. Whether you can get away with not doing it (to fill it at a later point) in practice is another question, I wouldn't risk it without a good reason.

I believe it's not guaranteed that `capacity` is actually used as the final string capacity (in practice it might be different for short SSO'd strings).

Comment: Technically, you are not answering the actual question ;-). How to resize without initializing... +1 anyway. Perhaps you could stress that resizing without overwriting is UB (with a lambda that does nothing).

Comment: @André ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I addressed that in the second-to-last paragraph. I'll tweak the wording a bit.